# How to connect 2 routers (Asmax and D-link) RJ11 vs RJ45 issue

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, adsl, wan

I just bought a new router, D-link DSL 2641B and want to connect it to another one, provided by my ISP, Asmax AR 804MP.

Previously, I had Linksys WRT350N, and there was no problem, while I had Ethernet cable plugged in to one of LAN ports in Asmax and INTERNET(RJ45) port in Linksys, connection used PPPoE protocol -- worked OK.

D-link has DSL(RJ11) port (which I don't want to use as Asmax replacement, while there is a separate Ethernet cable with a TV plugged to Asmax, which I don't want to configure from scratch on D-link).

How should I connect my new D-link to work with Asmax? Via DSL port? Via one of the LAN ports (in which case I probably should change the purpose of this port in the config, I guess?).

I tried connecting D-link both ways:

LAN(ASMAX) to LAN(DLINK)
LAN(ASMAX) to DSL(DLINK) (using RJ11 -> RJ45 cable)
I hope there is some setting in the DLINK's config that I overlooked.

I haven't tried to see what's in ASMAX's config, but I guess I don't need to change anything there, while Linksys worked just fine?

The only difference I see, is that D-link has RJ11 DSL port as WAN, and Linksys has RJ45 (called by them INTERNET) as a main WAN port.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Typically most home users won't want to connect one DSL router/modem to another router/modem. Also, I believe most users on serverfault are American, and might not be familiar with your D-link DSL 2641B (European?) and Asmax AR 804MP (Polish?) equipment.

Comment: Stefan: I'm trying to use D-link as a regular router(LANs for printers and wifi for other devices) *without* excluding Asmax to which my ISP (Dialog, and yes, I'm from Poland) connected a TV over Ethernet. I could exclude Asmax and use D-link alone,but this would require ISP's technician to come around and tell if it's possible which I'm trying to avoid, if possible.

Answer (score 6):

What you're doing makes no sense - stop it now.

The RJ11 port, on either box, is for the DSL link **ONLY**, it connects via your filter to your phone line and then onto the DSLAM using PPOA - it has nothing to do with ethernet ok.

You simply need to connect your machines together via IP and configure them to route between each other - if you can't do this then I'd suggest you ask this, modified, question on our sister-site superuser.com which is a much better forum for this type of question. Please read our FAQs before asking questions next time.